# Add a new Drupal page using custom module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am a Drupal newbie. I am using Drupal 7.26 and **I cannot create a new page using a custom module**.

I made a new module called my_page by creating my_page.info and my_page.module files inside the module's own directory, but I am confused about which hooks to implement. I just want to return plain static html in that page.

I know I can make a page using admin panel but I want to do this programatically.

**This is my .module code.**

```
function my_page_simple() {
  return array('#markup' => '<p>' . t('Simple page: The quick brown fox jumps over the     lazy dog.') . '</p>');
}
```

When I navigate to /my_page I get 'Page not found'

Comment: have u declared the `hook_menu` mate..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare a `hook_menu` function inside the my_page.module file.Since your module name is my_page your `hook_menu` will be named as `my_page_menu`.
`Hook_menu` enables modules to register paths in order to define how URL requests are handled. Paths may be registered for URL handling only, or they can register a link to be placed in a menu.

```
function my_page_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['my_page'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Page',
    'description' => 'Study Hard',
    'page callback' => 'my_page_simple', //Calls the function
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}   

function my_page_simple() {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  return array('#markup' => '<p>' . t('Simple page: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.') . '</p>');
}
```

After adding this try clearing the `drupal cache` and then navigate to `/my_page`.Try reading more about the `hook_menu` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).Hope this helps u mate.. :)